# Saída confusa de dados em CSV

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, csv, dicionário, collection

sou nov em Python e estou aprendendo a analisar e escrever arquivos em CSV. Estou preso em um problema que não consigo resolver há alguns dias: Estou tentando ler um banco de dados do governo, também em CSV, pegar algumas informações, calculá-las, e escrever um novo CSV com as informações ordenadas. (pra ser exato: estou contando o número de casos de feminicídio e tentativa de feminicidio por ano e a razão entre eles. A ideia é criar um CSV de quatro colunas com esses dados) O código é o seguinte:

```
import csv
import collections #biblioteca collections

#abre o arquivo
arq = open('fem.csv')
# cria o contador vazio
num = collections.Counter()
num2 = collections.Counter()

#laço for > itera no dicionário criado com o método DictReader do arquivo
for x in csv.DictReader(arq, delimiter=';') :
    num[x['ano']] += int(x['feminicidio_tentativa'])
    num2[x['ano']] += int(x['feminicidio'])

#print(num.most_common()) #most_common() recebe um parametro que limita o ranking
#criando um arquivo CSV com esses dados
arquivo_s = open('arquivo_saida.csv', mode='w', encoding = 'utf8')
esc = csv.writer(arquivo_s, delimiter=';', lineterminator='\n')
esc.writerow(['ano', 'feminicidio_tentativa', 'feminicidio', 'razão fem/tent'])

#itera em num e escreve ano, feminicidio nas primeiras duas colunas do csv
for ano,feminicidio_tentativa in  num.items() :
    esc.writerow([ano, feminicidio_tentativa])
# escreve o dado ONDE ELE QUISER ESSE ANARQUISTA DO *******
for ano,feminicidio in num2.items() :
    esc.writerow(['','', feminicidio, feminicidio/feminicidio_tentativa])

arquivo_s.close()
print('ok')
```

A saída, no entanto, fica assim:
[image: os dados "ano" e "feminicidio_tentativa" ficam nas primeiras linhas, os outros dados ficam nas colunas certas mas nas linhas abaixo]

Alguém sabe o que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Olá... Qual é a estrutura do arquivo 'fem.csv'?

Comment: O arquivo é uma planilha também em csv

Comment: Raposa, boa noite! coloque um dataset de teste com a estrutura do seu fem.csv. Abraço!